packing python wheel with pybind11 using bazel
I am trying to generate a wheel file using bazel, for a target that has pybind dependencies. The package by itself works fine (though testing), but when I'm packing it, the .so file is missing from the site_packges folder.
This is my build file:
load("@pybind11_bazel//:build_defs.bzl", "pybind_extension")
load("@python_pip_deps//:requirements.bzl", "requirement")
load("@rules_python//python:defs.bzl", "py_library", "py_test")
load("@rules_python//python:packaging.bzl", "py_wheel", "py_package")


# wrapper for so file
py_library(
    name = "example",
    srcs = ["example.py","__init__.py"],
    deps = [
    ],
    data = [":pyexample_inf"],
    
    imports = ["."],
)

# compile pybind cpp
pybind_extension(
    name = "pyexample_inf",
    srcs = ["pyexample_inf.cpp"],
    deps = [],
    linkstatic = True,
   
)

# test wrapper
py_test(
    name = "pyexample_test",
    srcs = ["tests/pyexample_test.py"],
    deps = [
        ":example",
    ],
    
)


# Use py_package to collect all transitive dependencies of a target,
# selecting just the files within a specific python package.
py_package(
    name = "pyexample_pkg",
    visibility = ["//visibility:private"],
    # Only include these Python packages.
    deps = [":example"],
    
)

#  using pip, this copies the files to the site_packges, but not the so file
py_wheel(
    name = "wheel",
    abi = "cp311",
    author = "me",
    
    distribution = "example",
    license = "Apache 2.0",
    platform = select({
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:linux_x86_64": "linux_x86_64",
    }),
     python_requires = ">=3.9.0",
    python_tag = "cpython",
    version = "0.0.1",
    deps = [":example"],
)

How can I make the py_wheel copy the so file?

try deps = [":example.so"]
